# ajax configuration in codeigniter

Tags: ajax

Why do I always get this error -
Fatal error: Call to undefined function js() in C:\xampp\htdocs\school\application\views\search_entry_view.php on line 66?

I have this code in my search_entry_view.php:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
Ges.baseurl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
});    
</script>
<?php echo js('assets/js/ges.js'); ?>
```

And this code in ges.js

```
var Ges = {
    baseurl: '',
    indexpage:'',

    search_by: function(){
        var search_by = $('#search_by').val();

        if (search_by === '1') {
            $('#grade').hide();
        }
        if (search_by === '2') {
            $('#teacher').hide();
        }
        if (search_by === '3') {
            $('#item').hide();
        }
        if (search_by === '4') {
            $('#sy').hide();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Script can't find `js()` function. As I remeber there is `js()` function in CI. Did you create `js()` ?

Answer (score 0):

If doesn't exists, try to create your own `js()`

**1. system/helper/url_helper.php**

add a function like :

```
if ( ! function_exists('js'))
{
    function js($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$CI->config->base_url($uri).'"></script>'
    }
}
```